# Is there any limit to the number of files that can be created in sysfs filesystem?

Tags: files, sysfs

Does Unix has any restriction on the number of files that can be created in sysfs filesystem? I am seeing a sysfs write error while:

Trying to add an entry under /sys/class/<> where already it has more than 500 entries.

Comment: What's the exact error? Where did you see it? In `dmesg` output? What were you doing that caused an entry to be added to `/sys/class/`?

Comment: You can not create any file/directory into `/sys` filesystem as it is reserved for kernel only. Kernel creates the structure. At max, you can alter the parameters/contents if the file permission allows

Comment: In any case, using `brctl addbr`, I can add a lot more than 500 entries to `/sys/class/net` without causing an error.

Comment: The files that is created under /sys filesystem is from the storage driver in our server. It basically adds the device information(like sas disks) that it discovers under sys/class/<>. The error that is displayed is "write error: Cannot allocate memory" during sysfs write.

Comment: Are you writing a kernel driver? If so, this isn't the place to ask: this site is for users and administrators, programming questions on off-topic. You can ask programming questions on [so], but you must show [complete code that reproduces the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1):

Yes - you are not supposed to create any files under `/sys`. This is a virtual file system which is managed by the kernel. Its purpose is to provide information about the system and attached devices. To this end it doesn't make sense that users create files there.